# Run .EXE and Powershell tasks with Airflow

Tags: airflow

our systems are basically just Windows Servers running C# and Powershell applications in conjunction with MS SQL Server. We have a in-house WorkflowManagement solution that is able to run tasks that execute EXE/BAT/PS1 and even call DLL-Functions.

Now I am evaluating if Apache Airflow is a better solution for us. My naive plan so far is to run airflow scheduler on a Linux-machine and then let the consumers run on Windows machines. But how would I setup the consumer to run a .exe task for instance?

Do I need to create a Wrapper-Service that takes HTTP-Calls and then executes the .Exe files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the consumers you are mentioning are called "workers" in airflow. The typical workers run an executor which doesn't run on Windows.

In theory you could install an ssh server on your windows boxes, and then use `SSHExecuteOperator` to run the exe commands and etc. there.

This would probably work better than an HTTP impl because your tasks in airflow would stay "running" while the ssh command was running and automatically go to success or fail accordingly. With an HTTP impl you would need to implement this functionality yourself if you wanted to integrate nicely with airflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found another, probably better solution: pywinrm! https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm With that you can use Windows Remote PowerShell via python. So I define a task via python and import the pywinrm library and then I can execute all the commands I want, like invoking an exefile

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question similar to this in

[Airflow Scheduler fails to execute Windows EXE via WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65402424/airflow-scheduler-fails-to-execute-windows-exe-via-wsl/69487192#69487192)