# Can we communicate with windows instance using GCP composer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I want to run my bat file on windows with the help of GCP Composer, but i am not sure if we can communicate with windows machine as composer is fully based on linux environment. Please help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple possible solutions described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628993/run-exe-and-powershell-tasks-with-airflow), basically:

1. Installing ssh into your Windows machine and then connecting to run commands remotely using the Airflow’s [ssh operator](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/connection/ssh.html).
2. Install a package like [pywinrm](https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm2/), which allows you to run Windows commands on a target machine from Python code. Then, use the [Python operator](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/operator/python.html), within your DAG, to make the call. You may refer to the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies) for steps on installing additional Python packages in Composer.