# Trigger Powershell from Airflow Task

Tags: powershell, airflow

I am new to Airflow. Want to trigger the powershell script located in windows from Airflow task. Tried achieving this using hook (FS, SSH, FTP) - failed.

How can we achieve running the powershell script from Airflow task.

my code looks like below...

```
def powershell_content(ds, **kwargs):
    ssh_hook = SSHHook('my_file_system')
    p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
                      "PSDateTest.ps1"],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate()
    print('success')   
   
powershell_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_the_context',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=powershell_content,
    dag=dagTest)
```

and the error is
{{models.py:1760}} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'powershell.exe': 'powershell.exe'

Comment: In order for anyone to find a solution to your problem you really should update your original question to include details on exactly how a specific attempt failed. Did you get an error message when using a specific hook, etc?

Does this answer your question? [Run .EXE and Powershell tasks with Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628993/run-exe-and-powershell-tasks-with-airflow)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I have added the code block in the question

Comment: So, are you getting any kind of error message?

Comment: yes, the error is '{{models.py:1760}} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'powershell.exe': 'powershell.exe'

Comment: Well, as the error suggests, the executable cannot be found. Have you tried adding the full path of powershell.exe, such as `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"` to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: tried even that, but the same error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe': 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe'

Comment: I think, Airflow cannot read the file/powershell available in windows. Please suggest how to access files available in windows from Airflow..